# The kernel failed to start as '_psutil_linux' could not be imported from 'most likely due to a circular import'. Juypyter notebook VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, linux-kernel

Getting this error when I try to run jupyter notebook. Just installed VScode.

Comment: give all the version info: OS, VS Code, extensions. If this happens with a particular notebook and not just in general, provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Jupyter extension[1](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter)?
I had the same error, but it was fixed after installing this extension.

OS: Ubuntu18.04
VSCode version: 1.75.1
Python: 3.10.9 (conda)